# Running java class file gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, json, classpath, gson

I have the following `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\TestObjectToJson.java` file:

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class TestObjectToJson{

  String state = "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";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestObjectToJson obj = new TestObjectToJson();
      Gson gson = new Gson();

      //convert java object to JSON format
      String json = gson.toJson(obj);

      System.out.println(json);
  }

}
```

I have downloaded the required Gson liberaries `(gson-2.2.4.jar, gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar, gson-2.2.4-sources.jar)` and unzipped them at

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com:

My CLASSPATH is set to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\gson-2.2.4.jar`

My program at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\TestObjectToJson.java`  gets compiled with the above CLASSPATH. But when I try to run, it gives me: `NoClassDefFoundError`

If I change the CLASSPATH to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\`

Then I am unable to compile the program: It gives me : `package com.google.gson does not exist.`

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Here is the copy paste from cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\Java>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com>set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\
com\gson-2.2.4.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com>javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0
\com\gson-2.2.4.jar"
```

TestObjectToJson.java

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com>java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0
\com\gson-2.2.4.jar" TestObjectToJson
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestObjectToJson

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\gson-2.2.4.jar
```

Comment: Post the complete exception, message, and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't have to write your code inside your Program File folder, it is even a bad practice that could make trouble when updating Java.

To specify the classpath you need to write something like this:

> java -classpath ".;c:\mylib*" MyApp

So in your case:

> javac - classpath ".;com\gson-2.2.4.jar" com\TestObjectToJson.java
>
> java - classpath ".;com\gson-2.2.4.jar" com.TestObjectToJson

You need to be at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\ to run this commands.

But remember that this location is not recommended.

To have more information about claspath in java:
[PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

or this: [How To Set The Classpath](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowToSetTheClasspath)

Last thing, IMHO, using Eclipse or Netbeans makes dependency issues much easier.

Edit after your update:

> C:\Program Files\Java>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0>javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1. 5.0\com\gson-2.2.4.jar" com\TestObjectToJson.java
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0>java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5 .0\com\gson-2.2.4.jar" com.TestObjectToJson

Comment: I am still getting the same error. SO have edited the original question.

Comment: Your not in the good place when calling your java file. You are at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\' you should be at ''C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\'

Comment: And you should call the complete package including "com."

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the classpath at runtime as well.

```
java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\gson-2.2.4.jar" -jar "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\com\TestObjectToJson.java"
```